Scaling TikZ shadings
I am a bit surprised that shadings declared with \pgfdeclare*shading have dimensions -- I thought it would just be the colors and the (relative) positions between the left and right and (for a linear shading). But playing around with
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{S}{0.1cm}{color(0cm)=(red); color(4cm)=(blue)}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \fill[shading=S, shading angle=0] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

seems to show that shadings have fixed dimensions. Is it possible to declare a shading with relative size?

Quote from the TikZ user guide:

Now, the ⟨shading name⟩ should be a shading whose width and height are 100bp, that is, 100 big points.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{S}{100bp}{color(0bp)=(red); color(100bp)=(blue)}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \fill[shading=S, shading angle=0] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Thank you, I did not find this sentence where I looked. I'm even more confused now, please have a look at the edited question.

@Bubaya Add \selectcolormodel{cmyk}, but that a completely different and unrelated problem. You shouldn't change a question like this after you've gotten an answer!

The problem here is that the area between 0bp and 25bp as well as between 75bp and 100bp will not be visisble: The shading is scaled and translated such that …. You need color(0bp)=(c1); color(25bp)=(c1); color(75bp)=(c2); color(100bp)=(c2);. TikZ's shadings are actually adding color(50bp)=(c3); where c3 is c1!50!c2.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Sorry, I was not aware that the color model was the problem, since the same colors are used for the rectangles and the gradient.

@Bubaya Please roll back your edit

@Qrrbrbirlbel is it the case that left color and right color put the colors at 25bp and 75bp then? Experimenting with rotated shadings seems to suggest that.
